# I need clarification on how apache works with modwsgi and pyramid

Tags: python, apache, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi, pyramid

We have a server that is configured to run a `pyramid+sqlalchemy` app with `modwsgi+apache2`

We have a few things in the `__init__.py` of the pyramid app to create database and prepopulate some test users and accounts. It is similar to the initialize_sql function in [pyramid cookbook example here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/database/sqlalchemy.html#importing-all-sqlalchemy-models)

Out apache config looks something like this (Copied from somewhere and hacked):

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=ubuntu group=staff processes=1 \
   threads=4 \
   python-path= VIRTUAL_ENV_SITE_PACKAGES
WSGIScriptAlias / WSGI_SCRIPT_PATH

<Directory /Users/chrism/modwsgi/env>
  WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Whats been bothering us is that the `initialize_function` gets called on many requests instead of just being called once. We do not understand how apache works or what we have done in the config. We want to be able to call the functions in `__init__.py` once and thats it. Can someone explain how apache actually works and why pyramid `__init__.py` is being reloaded all the time. Also explain how we can make sure that the `__init__.py` is not rerun every request

Consider sharing simple to understand links regarding the same stuff :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like creating a database and prepopulating it shouldn't go into the `__init__.py` file of a WSGI application because, as you've noticed, this file gets run whenever you start your server (and at certain other points as well).

What you need is a script which can be called from the command line whenever you need to. Every framework provides their own way to build these. In Pyramid they are called `console scripts`. [Here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#making-your-script-into-a-console-script) you can find the documentation of how to build one yourself.

However, I recommend you use the scaffold (project template) from [this tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/tutorials/wiki2/installation.html#making-a-project) and have a look at the console script called `initialize_tutorial_db`. It does exactly what you want and allows you to create / initialize your database from the command line whenever you need to.

---

Regarding the apache configuration, the line which is relevant to your question is the following:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=ubuntu group=staff processes=1 \
   threads=4 \
   python-path= VIRTUAL_ENV_SITE_PACKAGES
```

It means you will start **1** process with **4** threads. This shouldn't mean that the code in your `__init__.py` file is run multiple times. That is more likely to be caused from you restarting the server manually or through code changes.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that multiple instances of the `WSGIDaemonProcess` are spawned to handle all the requests coming into Apache. It's even possible that within these processes, several threads are created to handle requests (mostly) simultaneously. You should try to guard your initialize_function() such that it only runs once per process (or thread), for example by keeping track of if it's run already. In general, it's probably better to scope your actions/resource management to a request's lifetime.

Comment: scoping our actions/resource management to a request's lifetime is not an option because we are trying to build a highly async app.